# How do I install software/tools in an ubuntu virtual machine using a terminal?

Tags: software-installation, virtualization, multipass

I'm studying comp-sci but haven't been able to figure out how to install stuff in my ubuntu vm. I'm using Windows 10 with an ubuntu vm downloaded through Multipass with VSC as the intended editor. Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-125-generic x86_64)

What I need to install are:

- A C compiler (and standard libraries): The most commonly used are either gcc (https://gcc.gnu.org) or clang (https://clang.llvm.org).
- Make, where GNU is what's recommended for us
- A debugger, e.g. gdb (https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/) or lldb (https://lldb.llvm.org )
- A tool for checking code coverage, e.g. gcov + (lcov or gcovr)
- A performance analysis tool, e.g. gprof
- A tool for checking memory leaks, e.g. valgrind (https://valgrind.org)
- A java development environment, e.g. openjdk (https://openjdk.org)

I found `git clone git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git SomeLocalDir` and ran it in my vm terminal which worked but I'm not 100% certain it's installed as it should be and neither am I sure where it was installed.

According to instructions, we're supposed to copy+paste:

```
$ sudo apt install -y build-essential binutils clang libclang-dev lldb libcunit1-dev \
       gcovr lcov valgrind default-jdk-headless
```

Which returned `package not found` for all parts. I assume this is because I haven't downloaded the source? If so, where should I download the source to and how? Does the file type matter for a beginner?

Sorry for expanding the question beyond the intended subject.

---

Thank you for the help,`sudo apt update` worked, I updated everything and the installation started.

During the download an issue came up though  
 `paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)`.   
I tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install` 
After this didn't work I tried to download the whole thing again and it went the same way. 
Now what `sudo apt --fix-broken install` returns is: 
 `dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: unable to fill /var/lib/dpkg/updates/tmp.i with padding: No space left on device`  
 `E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)` 
`E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)`

Comment: You've provided no actual Ubuntu product/release details.  Did you update your VMs software lists (ie. `sudo apt update`) so it was aware of what is available? (*on new machines it's best to not assume this has already been done, some product/releases do this during installation, others do not - and you've not said what product/release you're using so we won't know*)

Comment: I wonder if you're installed an old, unsupported Ubuntu release in your VM

Comment: `sudo apt install clang` and that will also pull in many required support apps. Names are not always what you may think. I often used synaptic gui app to find exact name. But you cannot have synaptic open when installing from command line as it will give an error. `sudo apt install synaptic`

Comment: The `apt` command you quoted should work. It's a common method to install these tools. The message `package not found` is because `apt` somehow can't find the named packages in the repositories. What is the contents of your repository config file `/etc/apt/sources.list` ? Also, as someone noted, did you do `sudo apt update` to pull in the recent contents of the repositories?